# Exactly once delivery with multiple consumers and bulk reads

Tags: java, redis, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, jms

I've been reading about messaging queues recently. Since I am new to the topic, I was not able to decide on a framework because I am not comfortable with the features of them. For a project I'll be working on, I'm trying to decide whether the following bullets are possible together. In which frameworks/technology can I achieve these? Any pros or cons?

- Exactly once delivery in which all messages are also read exactly once (not once each consumer).
- Multiple producers and consumer for high availability reasons.
- Bulk read and process messages by consumers (it is not scalable to process messages one by one).
- Nonblocking read (each consumer picks different messages and processes them without waiting for other consumers to finish their tasks).

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "bulk read"? Messages themselves are typically considered individual units so most APIs will also treat them as such, but a lot of messaging solutions will provide "batching" functionality via transactions (e.g. so all the consumed messages can be acknowledged at once). Is something like that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JustinBertram By bulk read I mean, consumers can read many messages like 100 or 1000 and then process them at once instead of read one process one. Again along with this, consumed messages should also be acknowledged at once.

Comment: I don't know of any messaging solution that combines the consumption of multiple messages into a single process.  I'm not even sure that makes sense conceptually as the messages would still be individual units that the process would need to loop through which is not substantially different than the client consuming the messages individually in the first place. Also, if the idea is to parallelize consumption that is usually done by just increasing the number of consumers.

Comment: It seems to me that instead of stating the underlying problem you wish to solve you're listing the ways you want to solve the problem. The issue with that approach is that you miss alternative approaches to solving your underlying problem that may be at least as good or even better than the ways you've envisioned.

Comment: You may be right but unfortunately I cannot share the details. Processing each message separately requires SSL connection setup. This is costly. So consumer has to read a batch of messages(if pulling 100 messages is not an option, you, can assume pulling a message 100 times).

Comment: Are you under the impression that every message requires setting up an SSL connection? I know for a fact that is false for messaging solutions like Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. In Artemis you can create a *single* SSL connection per client and all the messages you want can be received over that single connection - even to multiple consumers in the same JVM. There are even ways to configure a "window" where multiple messages are fetched from the broker at once to avoid network round-trips. However, those messages are still delivered to the client API one at a time.

Comment: I don't know about the connection between consumer and brokers but in order to process a message I need to create an SSL connection and do some operations. I don't want to make this connection for each message. Since I'll process them in bulks, I asked for if I can read them in bulks.

Comment: That's exactly my point. You don't have to create an SSL connection for each message, but you still won't process the messages in bulk as you've described (which I'm still not even sure makes sense conceptually). With ActiveMQ Artemis, for example, you can create a single SSL connection per client, fetch the messages from the broker "in bulk" (more accurately "in chunks"), and then process them one at a time. To be clear, even processing messages "one at a time" can be extremely fast. You can process millions of messages per second in certain scenarios.